# (of which) Seventy (of which) are from the northern region

Tags: meaning, usage, word-order

I have a question about the meaning of two different sentences:

> 1. The battalion consists of two hundred soldiers, ***seventy of which*** are from the northern region, ***stationed along the coast***.
> 2. The battalion consists of two hundred soldiers, ***of which seventy*** are from the northern region, ***stationed along the coast***.

In sentences 1 & 2, does "*stationed along the coast*" apply to all two hundred soldiers of the battalion, or just the seventy soldiers from the northern region?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that neither sentence clearly states that seventy northern soldiers are stationed along the coast.

To say that, the sentence could be:

> The battalion consists of two hundred soldiers, of which seventy from
>   the northern region are stationed along the coast.

On the other hand, if you want to convey that the northerners are generally part of the battalion:

> The battalion stationed along the coast consists of two hundred
>   soldiers, seventy of which are from the northern region.

Or the other variant "of which seventy . . ."

Comment: So, in sentence 1, "***stationed along the coast***" applies to the entire battalion?  And in sentence 2, "***stationed along the coast***" applies only to the seventy soldiers from the northern region?

Comment: No I tried to make it clear it is the other way round.

Comment: Sorry do you mean sentence 1 of the question, or sentence 1 of my answer?

Comment: So, in sentence 1 of my question, "***stationed along the coast***" applies to the entire battalion? And in sentence 2 of my question, "***stationed along the coast***" applies only to the seventy soldiers from the northern region?

Comment: The problem with your sentences is they are trying to say three things about the battalion: its size, its makeup, and its duties, and these should be separated to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to parse this shite and have it make sense is to understand the adjunct  **stationed along the coast** as applying to the battalion:

> The battalion, stationed along the coast, consists of two hundred
>   soldiers, seventy of which are from the northern region.

Why? Normally the adjunct would apply to the preceding noun-phrase, but inasmuch as the **northern region** cannot be **stationed**, that leaves the **battalion** and **soldiers** and **seventy of which** as candidates.

We can rule  out **seventy of which** because we'd need **are**   in that case:

> ...seventy of which|of which seventy, from the northern region,
>   **are** stationed along the coast.

The reason for eliminating **two hundred soldiers** is more tenuous; it has to do with the meaning of the verb **consists**. The word **consists**, on the semantic level, wants a complement that *defines*, whereas their being stationed along the coast is not integral to who they are; they *happen to be* stationed along the coast, unless this battalion is a coastal battalion, in which case we'd want some sort of phrase to make that clear:

> The battalion consists of two hundred soldiers stationed along the coast rather than in a single barracks.